# Java getClass and super classes

Tags: java, superclass

```
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o)
        return true;
    if ((o == null) || (this.getClass() != o.getClass()))
        return false;
    else {
        AlunoTE umAluno = (AlunoTE) o;
        return(this.nomeEmpresa.equals(umAluno.getNomeEmpresa()) && super.equals(umAluno);
    }
}
```

Could anyone explain me how the fourth line (`(this.getClass() != o.getClass())`) works when the argument is a super class? Because the classes have different names. `this.getClass` will return a different name than `o.getClass`, right?

Comment: It's not confusing, it just seems trivial: if it's an instance of a superclass, it's not the same class, yes? As such, `!=` would be true.

Comment: Yes I understand that, but I thought it was supposed to return true even if the class given as argument is a superclass of the class where this method is defined as long as that superclass had a subclass equal to this one.

Comment: If the current instance (the this pointer) is an AlunoTE (assumed to be the class this code is in based on code snippet) and the object passed in is a *SUBCLASS* of AlunoTE, then this.getClass() will not equal o.getClass().  You should instead check for if (!(o instanceof AlunoTE)).  Checking if something is an instanceof a class allows safe type casting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the following code snippet which answers your question. Object O can hold any object. o.getClass() will return the run time class of the object

```
public class Main {
  void method(Object o) {
    System.out.println(this.getClass() == o.getClass());
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Main().method(new Object());  // false
    new Main().method(new Main());    // true
    new Main().method(new String());  // false
    new Main().method(new MainOne()); // false
  }
}

class MainOne extends Main
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So lets say there are two classes. Class A and Class B. Class A is a super class of class B. So this method would be in class B. "this.getClass()" refers to an object of class B while o.getClass()(The super class) will refer to class A. So Class B will not equal Class A. Meaning it will go into the if statement.

Comment: Yes and No.  This method would be in class A.  If this is of type A and o is of type B, then the equals check will fail because it is not an exact class type match.  It doesn't check for whether o is an instance of A.  It checks if this' class (an A) is equal to o's class (a B).

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your super class is SHAPE and you have a class RECT that is a subclass of SHAPE.
If the this variable is for a RECT and the Object o is also a RECT,
then line 4 will return true because they are the same class (RECT).
The two objects will be equal as long as their types are the same at runtime.

However, if Object o is of type SQUARE, which also subclasses SHAPE,
(and could even subclass RECT).
then it will not be equal to the this pointer (RECT), 
because their classes are different at runtime.

---

Now for why this kind of type checking is bad in the equals method (specifically for the use case of **Hibernate** entity classes).

If you use Hibernate and you are checking a newly created object whose class type is RECT against an object whose class type was RECT at the time it was cached in Hibernate, the class of the object in the cache will actually be a sub-class of type RECT, because Hibernate does byte-code manipulation and wraps the objects in a synthetic sub-class (RECT_$$javassist).

***This means that your Hibernate cached objects that you expect to be equal will never be equal.***

If the object is in a child collection, Hibernate will assume you wanted to delete the old object from the collection and create the new object in the collection instead of doing a (potential) update on an existing object in the collection.
We have legacy code that did this and could never figure out why (until now) it kept doing deletes and re-inserts on our collection.

For Hibernate entity objects you should use the instanceof operator to determine if two objects could be equal - and then cast Object o and continue the comparison operation with class SHAPE specific fields.

If your subclasses should not be considered equal, then you will have to implement equals() in each subclass to check for instanceof.

---

For other use cases, you will have to determine if there is a chance that someone (or some other library) could sub-class your Class (even through byte code manipulation) and whether any sub-classes should still be considered equal or not.

For instance, if you do any kind of mocking in your unit tests, a bad equals method may cause otherwise equal objects to be non-equal due to their classes not being equal.

---

Back to the OP's code.  A better way to code the equals method would be:

```
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o)
        return true;
    if (!(o instanceof AlunoTE))
        return false;
    AlunoTE umAluno = (AlunoTE) o;
    return(this.nomeEmpresa.equals(umAluno.getNomeEmpresa()) && super.equals(umAluno);
}
```

Because the instanceof operator always returns false for null, there is no need for a null check too.